# Add custom logger and configuration for a @Feign

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I've created a custom logger

```
public class FeignCustomLogger extends Logger {
    /.../
}
```

Here is my Feign interface:

```
@FeignClient(name = "my-book", url = "${partner.my-book.rest-client.base-url}")
public interface MyBookFeignRestClient {
    /.../
}
```

Is it possible to add my logger into the FeignClient?
I need it for making logs of requests and responses in a special pattern

Answer (score 3):

To customize feign in spring-boot, you must use separate configuration class (it's better to **not** mark it as `@Configuration`).
There you should create `feign.Logger` bean.

Client:

```
@FeignClient(
    name = "my-book", 
    url = "${partner.my-book.rest-client.base-url}", 
    configuration = MyBookFeignConfiguration.class
)
public interface MyBookFeignRestClient {
```

And configuration:

```
class MyBookFeignConfiguration {
    @Bean
    Logger myBookResFeignLogger() {
        return new FeignCustomLogger();
    }
}
```

See [this chapter in documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults) for details.